# gmm Error: Incorrect number of dimensions

Tags: r

I would like to apply a gmm estimation in R and use an individual function *g* as a formula for the moment restrictions:

```
library(sandwich)
library(gmm)

#set up data for 10 observations and asume a linear function y~x
intercept <- 1
beta <- 1
x <- 1:10
e <- rnorm(10)
y <- intercept + beta*x + e

#generate matrix
data <- cbind(x,y)

#define function g with moments restrictions for gmm estimation
g <- function(data,theta){
    x <- data[,1]
    y <- data[,2]
    tmp <- x*(y-theta*x)
    return (tmp)
}

estimation <- gmm(g,data)
```

The example above results in the error:

```
Error in data[,1]: Incorrect number of dimensions.
```

I get

```
dim(data)
[1] 10 2

data[,1]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Apart from the statistic model being a very simple example on learning gmm, what am i doing wrong with my data with regards to the dimensions of my variables?

Comment: At the moment I see no value for theta.

Comment: theta is a free parameter, estimated by the model. One can define a starting value for optimization as a parameter in ‚gmm(g,data,t0=startingValue)‘

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my flaw, wich is due to the definition of the function *g*.
As the [reference manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmm/gmm.pdf) for gmm in R states, *g* can be a formula (if you use linear models) or an explicit function with two parameters. The declaration of *g* as a function must be the estimated vector of parameter *theta* as the **first** argument and the matrix of data *x* as the **second** argument. In fact,

```
g <- function(data,theta){
...
}
```

has to be replaced by

```
g <- function(theta,data){
...
}
```

Comment: Did you get rid of the error after the replacement? I have the totally same problem as you, though my order of the arguments is right.

Comment: Yes, the error no longer occurs if the arguments are placed within the right order. Maybe your case could be an own question on this site.

Comment: can you please take a look at my answer if you have time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65781259/plot-causes-error-incorrect-number-of-dimensions-r-language thanks!